# implement excel-like filter menus kendo jquery

Tags: jquery, kendo-ui, kendo-grid

I am using Kendo grid UI for Jquery Library.

I have a need to do the following two things with my grid's column filter menu dropdown checkboxes:

1) Sort the checkboxes alphabetically by their value (by default the are sorted by the grid's datasource sort value).

2) Filter all other column's checkbox values based on the filter selection of the first checkbox.

Comment: Did you try anything? Can you post some code?

Comment: $("#grid").kendoGrid({filterable: true, columns:[{field: Accountid,filterable:{multi: true,search:true}}],
  dataSource: {

  }, 
pageable: true


});

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example of sort and filter. You just have to add filterable and sortable to your kendoGrid initialization.

```
    $("#grid").kendoGrid({
  dataSource: {

  }, 
  filterable: {
      extra: false,
      operators: {
          string: {
              startswith: "Starts with",
              eq: "Is equal to",
              neq: "Is not equal to"
          }
      }
  },
  sortable: {
    mode: "multiple",
    allowUnsort: true,
    showIndexes: true
},
  pageable: true


});
```

Comment: The above example does not apply Filters in check boxes. I need to  Filter all other column's checkbox values based on the filter selection of the first checkbox.

Answer (score 0):

Working Demo: https://codepen.io/ezanker/pen/PRwPLo

To sort the checkboxes you can use the **[filterMenuInit event](https://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/ui/grid/events/filtermenuinit)**. Get all the LI items into an array and sort them, then add them back to the UL. In this example, I keep the Select All option in the first position:

```
filterMenuInit: function(e) {
        var items = e.container.find("li").get();
        items.sort(function(a,b){
            var keyA = $(a).text();
            var keyB = $(b).text();

            if (keyA < keyB) return -1;
            if (keyA > keyB) return 1;
            return 0;
        });
        var ul = e.container.find("ul");
        $.each(items, function(i, li){
            if ($(li).find('.k-check-all').length > 0){
                ul.prepend(li); //keep select all first
            } else {
                ul.append(li); // This moves theli from the old spot
            }
        });
    }, //end filterMenuInit
```

To apply filter selections in one column to all columns, use the **[fiter event](https://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/ui/grid/events/filter)**. In here I loop through the other columns and build the same filter for them. Given that column filters are ANDed, only rows with the same values will be returned i.e. in the example check item1 in the first column filter and only the one row where all columns have item1 will be displayed. If you want an OR, change `thefilter.logic = "and";` to `thefilter.logic = "or";`

```
filter: function(e) {
    grid = e.sender;
    if (e.filter == null) {
        grid.dataSource.filter(null);                          
        grid.refresh();
        $("form.k-filter-menu button[type='reset']").trigger("click");                          
    } else {
        //build filters object for all fields
        var thefilter = {};
        thefilter.logic = "and";
        thefilter.filters = [];
        for (var i=0; i<colFields.length; i++){
            if (e.field == colFields[i]) continue;
            var colfilt = {"logic": e.filter.logic};
            var filters = [];
            for (var j=0; j<e.filter.filters.length; j++){
                var filt = {};
                filt.field = colFields[i];
                filt.operator = e.filter.filters[j].operator;
                filt.value = e.filter.filters[j].value;
                filters.push(filt);
            }
            colfilt.filters = filters;
            thefilter.filters.push(colfilt);
        }

        grid.dataSource.filter(thefilter);
    }
}//end filter
```

**NOTE: clearing the filter in one column is not clearing the filters in the other columns. You will need to solve that issue.**

Comment: Thanks very much for your answer. I tried the above approach. But, the problem is i am using 2016R2 kendo ui version for jquery. . This version of kendo ui does not have Filter event for KendoGrid. So, i cannot use Filter event of Kendo Grid. Anyother way to achieve Filter of all other column's checkbox values based on the filter selection of the first checkbox

Comment: I have upgraded my kendo library to 2017 and now Filter event is firing. But, actually my requirement is to :-  1.] If we filter the value in one column, then the value in the corresponding column for the same row must also be checked even though the value of that row is different.

Comment: @sai, try changeing the filter logic of the overall filter to "or" instead of "and":  thefilter.logic = "or";

Comment: i tried but still it is not working. please find a example which i am trying:- https://dojo.telerik.com/IJAGoWur/7

Comment: Even though i specify  thefilter.logic = "or" still it sets overall filter to "and"

Comment: @sai, i have updated my codepen: https://codepen.io/ezanker/pen/PRwPLo it seems to work. The problem with your DOJO is all the columns have different data, so it makes no sense to set the filters the same

Comment: Yes that is the problem,my requirement is that even though all the columns have different data they belong to one row in a datasource and If a filter is applied on a column in a row, filter must also be applied on the corresponding column in the same row.

Comment: @sai, i guess I don't really understand the requirement. if columns have different data, they won't have the same checkboxes in the filter popup and it makes no sense to apply the same filter...

Comment: the business analyst looks at it as one datasource row binded to different columns in kendogrid.

Comment: So, if a filter is applied on one column then for the same datasource row corresponding column filter must also be applied even though data is different .                                                                                                                                                        Is my requirement clear?